# Interfacing with a cell of a multi-column WinList control during CodedUI testing

Tags: c#, user-interface, coded-ui-tests

I am having difficulty interfacing with a cell (not sure if these are truly cells) in a multi-column WinList.  I am testing a windows application.  I have queried the dialog with multiple tools and the control is clearly a WinList and not a WinTable.

I would like the ability to accomplish 3 things:

1)  Read the value of a cell.
 
2)  Edit the value of a cell.
3)  Mouse click on a cell

I have been able to accomplish ‘Reading from a cell’ (item #1) using the following code:

```
var value = new WinListItem(myGetList(myListId).Items[3]).GetColumnValues()[1];
```

When it comes to editing or mouse clicking on a cell, I can’t find any way to locate them.

First I tried to cast the WinList as a WinTable so that I could use the more robust WinTable properties:

```
var table = (WinTable)(myGetList(myListId));
```

This was a failure.

I also tried to instantiate a table using the WinList:

```
var table = new WinTable(myGetList(myListId);
```

This was also a failure.

I am testing a dynamic application and try to avoid using screen coordinates, as well as the UImap.  I find those methods lack durability and would like to use code whenever possible.

Can anyone help me achieve items 2 & 3 from above using code?

Answer (score 1):

The UIMap is only as durable as the code within it.  As there's two partial classes to the map (map.designer.cs and map.cs), I would use the map.cs partial class and create an object the same way you did in step 1.

```
// Here, you've created a WinListItem
new WinListItem(myGetList(myListId).Items[3])

// so, let's extrapolate that:
public WinListItem MyListItem(int row, int column)
{
    WinListItem target = new WinListItem(myGetList(myListId).Items[row]);
    UITestControlCollection columns = target.GetChildren();
    return (WinListItem)columns[column];
}
```

Now, you can send `MyWinListItem(3, 1).DisplayText = "blah";` and `Mouse.Click(MyWinListItem(3, 1));` to perform requirements 2 and 3.